# (Redux Toolkit) How to access the state outside of the createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my project, I want to put as much as logic and function inside the the `slice.js`. Sometime I want to create or export the function outside of the `createSlice` like this:

````
const checkValid = () => {
   ```need to access the current state to check for validation```
}

export const boardSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'board',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
       check: (state, actions) => {
         checkValid(actions.payload);
       }
    }
});
````

The `checkValid` need to access the state in the `store`, my current solution is directly passing the state as props along with the `actions.payload` in the `reducer`. But is there a better or official way of doing this? Also, is it good to put as much as logic inside the slice? Much appreciated.

Comment: Using `state` is the faster way to access state. Its right there :P

Comment: Where is the `state` that is stored in `store` coming from? From another slice? If so, how are you using it?

Comment: yeah, so I have to do ```checkValid(actions.payload, state.count)``` to pass it into the function above, is there a method to access the state directly in the function above?

Answer (score -1):

Let me share with you what am using, hope it helps

```
mport { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authService from "Services/authService";
import { logOutUser } from "Services/userServices";

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initialState = {
  user: user ? user : null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

// Register user
export const register = createAsyncThunk("user/register", async (user, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    return await authService.register(user);
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString();
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
  }
});

// Login user
export const login = createAsyncThunk("user/login", async (user, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = user;
    const res = await authService.loginUser(username, password);
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString();
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
  }
});

export const logout = createAsyncThunk("user/logout", async () => {
  try {
    return await logOutUser();
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString();
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
  }
});

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.message = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(register.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(register.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(register.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        state.user = null;
      })
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        state.user = null;
      })
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.isSuccess = true;
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        localStorage.removeItem("user");
        state.user = null;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

for more clalification on the use of extra reducers
checkout this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvfsC66xqj0

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Looking for how you can manuplate the return action payload, You cab do it in the extra reducers,